# Windows 10 app running within debugger contains text on top left corner with a black stripe

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10, monogame

I need to know what it means when there is text with a black stripe on top left corner of a Windows 10 app when I run it from Visual Studio debugger (C#) as shown below:

[image: Windows 10 app]

Also, how to hide this text with a black stripe?

Comment: http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/10/21/how-to-turn-off-the-frame-rate-counters-for-windows-universal-apps/

Answer (score 2):

This strip is known as FrameRateCounter. For Windows 8.1 before publishing in release mode we had to disable this counter. Now in windows 10 its precoded to work in Debug mode only.
In App.xaml

```
#if DEBUG
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            }
#endif
```

Making this as `false` will disable the frameratecounter in debug mode also. Else you can deploy as Release version instead.
FramerateCounter is used to monitor the performance of your app, including [frames per second and memory usage](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2077111&seqNum=4). This is quite helpful in mobile devices with lesser computing power.